# Using t.co in sharekit - iphone application

Tags: twitter, sharekit, url-shortener

I am using sharekit but I don't want to use the bityl service for shortening the URL I want to use the built-in t.co provided by twitter.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [T.co](https://support.twitter.com/entries/109623) is not available as an API to developers. It's an internal shortner used by Twitter to automatically shorten long links.

Check out [this post by Raffi](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/14d5474c13ed84aa), Twitter developer, to learn more about it.

You won't be able to control how the links get shortened. But all URL's over 20 characters are automatically shortened and you **can control what get's shortened** by including `wrap_links=true` on the `POST` you send to Twitter for new messages.

If you enable [entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) in the response you'll see the following attributes for your links.

```
"urls": [
        {
          "url": "http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",
          "display_url": "blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitte…",
          "expanded_url": "http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitter-for-mac-update.html",
          "indices": [
            84,
            103
          ]
        }
      ],
```

---

*For further reference :*

[Twitter's t.co URL wrapper is now on for all URLs 19 characters and greater](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1062)

[Next steps with the t.co link wrapper](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/next-steps-with-the-tco-link-wrapper)

---

Edit --->

***How to get this working with ShareKit:***

Twitter does not release an API like [bit.ly does](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) for URL's but if you look through the ShareKit library you will see the following file,

```
/ShareKit/master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Twitter/SHKTwitter.m
```

open this file and look for the following line:

`http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt`

inside the block

```
self.request = [[[SHKRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt",
                                                                          SHKBitLyLogin,
                                                                          SHKBitLyKey,                                                                        
                                                                          SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)
                                                                          ]]
```

This is the short URL string ShareKit sends to the Twitter sharer.

**I haven't had a chance to test this out**, but I think if you change this text string to a long URL text string then ShareKit will instead send that one.

Although there may be areas elsewhere in the framework that rely on the Bit.Ly service so watch out for that. But it's worth testing out.

Even though Twitter does not offer a T.co API, as of [Aug 15](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/next-steps-with-the-tco-link-wrapper) it has started translating all links to t.co. So, if you use a long URL with the steps mentioned above then you should be seeing T.co in the response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but how can I use this T.co in Sharekit?

Comment: Naveed, did you have a chance to test this out?

Comment: ok great thanks. so you mean it will be by default we don't need to do anything with links? I am using bityl using sharekit and it is working fine.

Comment: yeah, you won't need to do anything with the links. Change the URL `http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt` to your regular link. You should be seeing the `t.co` then.