# iOS ShareKit custom protocol link not a hyperlink in facebook or twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, hyperlink, sharekit

I have ShareKit setup and it is finally sharing with all that I mean for it to (tumblr, twitter and facebook). However, tumblr is the only one I could get to recognize my custom protocol url as a hyperlink. (i.e. myapp://thingy=4) For Twitter I had to disable the bit.ly URL shortening because it didn't recognize it as a link and Facebook wouldn't take the url share with the url saying it was an invalid url, so I had to send it as just a text share.

So is there any way to make a custom protocol link in twitter or facebook?

I am using the latest build from https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Comment: consider sending the link through an http proxy. Twitter/Facebook won't recognize custom protocols as links. Also see my answer here, not completely the same but may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125417/using-t-co-in-sharekit-iphone-application/7125726#7125726

Comment: Yeah, ended up thinking that up yesterday morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a "redirector" web service and hosting it on heroku. It's a pain, but it seems to be the only decent workaround.